# What is the meaning of "behind by thirty-five cents" and "ahead by sixty-five cents"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "behind by thirty-five cents" and "ahead by sixty-five cents" in the following sentence,

> "Wait!" shouted Mrs. Proons. She opened the violin case and gave the
>   farmer a dollar. "Your reward," she said and jumped back into the car.
>   The farmer looked at the money. He looked at Millie. "This morning,'
>   he said, "when we were paying our bills, we were behind by thirty-five
>   cents. Now we're ahead by sixty-five cents. Doesn't that seem a bit odd?"

Does "We were behind by thirty-five cents. Now we're ahead by sixty-five cents"
mean "We had less than thirty-five cents. Now We have more than sixty-five cents" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that at first, they fell short of paying the full amount. The amount that was still due was 35 cents. E. g., they had to pay 50 dollars and 35 cents (for example, the rent is $50.35), but they only had 50 dollars. So they paid what they had (50 dollars), and they were 35 cents short—they still **owed** this amount. But then they found an $1 bill somewhere — and when they paid it, their payment was *more* than they needed to cover those 35 cents. So they became "ahead" by 65 cents in their payment to someone—meaning, they **overpaid** someone by 65 cents.

This way of speaking comes from thinking about sums of money as a sort of a progression in time. If you look at the image below, X is the correct amount that should be paid (if they pay it, they neither owe money, nor have they overpaid). If you've paid more than you needed to pay, you've sort of "run ahead" of your schedule of payment. If you haven't paid enough, you are "behind".

[image: ahead or behind on payments]

In fact, there is an idiomatic saying:

> I'm behind on my bills.

It means that I have not paid all of my bills; I owe money to my landlord and/or to the utilities companies. One can be, for example "two months behind" (meaning, you haven't paid your rent for two months already). Or one can be X dollars behind (whatever sum you still owe to be all square on your payments).

Comment: I like your answer, especially the multi-colored graph, but I've never heard the phrase ***x* dollars behind.** Could that be part of a dialect maybe?

Comment: @Ringo Well, technically, one should say "x dollars behind _on_ something" (e. g. mortgage payments, rent, whatever). [Lots of results](https://www.google.com/search?q="dollars+behind+on"&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). I'm seeing results from California, Oregon, Indiana, [New York](https://books.google.com/books?id=rMEqAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT7&lpg=PT7&dq="dollars+behind+on"), so I don't think it is regional. Maybe no one ever felt comfortable admitting to you that they had financial difficulties, or these difficulties were exactly month-scale-related, so that's why you've never heard this phrase said. :)

Comment: @Ringo [Here, the New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/1992/05/30/nyregion/helping-deadbeat-dads-get-jobs-and-pay-support.html?pagewanted=all) writes, "Each [man] was unemployed and **thousands of dollars behind on** his court-ordered child-support payments." This would have gone through an editor armed with the NYT manual of style. Definitely not a dialect then, or even colloquial.

Comment: @Ringo I agree with tenebris2020.  To be some amount of money *behind* is not dialect, although it may be an *American* expression.

Comment: I am obviously confused somewhat and sorry about that. What I meant to say is that I don't think "behind on my payments/rent" or "x dollars behind" are idiomatic phrases. "Behind" itself is an adverb used to describe someone who is late in payments. If you wanted to, you can say "I'm behind" as a complete thought. Whatever modifiers you use to describe how far you're behind (or how much you're behind) aren't a part of any idiom per se. Check out definition "3b" under "adverb" in the Merriam Webster Learner's Dictionary: http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/behind

Comment: @Ringo "idiom" is [" an expression whose meaning is not predictable from the usual grammatical rules of a language or from the _usual meanings_ of its constituent elements"](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/idiom) (Webster's). The **core** meaning of "behind" deals with _location_ with respect to some other object. The very fact that a learner did not understand the phrase although they understand the _usual meaning_ of "behind" kinda proves it's idiomatic. Also, "idiomatic" is ["conforming to the usual manner of expression in a language."](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/idiomatic)

Comment: You're using **behind** idiomatically but the idea of *falling behind* (or being *in arrears*) on money owed comes from the word meaning "delayed" or "tardy" since the 14th century, not "from thinking about sums of money as a sort of a progression in time". Bills have come due in coordination with the calendar for a very very long time.  And so it's not an American expression either.

Comment: (spelling modernized) From 1445 : *And [if] they be behind of any such payment*  . and from 1430: *... for the said rent.. if it be behind at any time.* (per the *Middle English Dictionary*)

Comment: This conversation makes me want to drink Olde English.
https://78.media.tumblr.com/32a2bdc0c814054baf0b372377fa9561/tumblr_oyszn8sBzg1thg9w7o1_1280.jpg

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo What if I've paid on time, but I haven't paid enough (like in the case we have here—short by 35 cents)? Is this a binary have-paid/haven't-paid? Or is a certain amount (not the whole bill) delayed?

Comment: @tenebris2020: What if you were late by only 34 cents? Or only 17? Or perhaps by only a penny? You would be **behind** *by that amount*.